# Django oscar cannot import 'Basket' and 'Order'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-oscar

i'm running into an issue where the oscar library attempts to import 'oscar.apps.orderoscar'.
throwing the following error:

> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 139, in
> import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
> level)   File "", line 1050, in
> _gcd_import   File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
> "", line 241, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File "", line
> 1027, in _find_and_load   File "", line
> 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'oscar.apps.orderoscar'

It seems to me that the logical import should be 'oscar.apps.order' ('as is defined in the INSTALLED_APPS array) but it somehow won't trigger that import.

I've ran the following command to grab all the 'oscar.apps.orderoscar' occurences within my django project: $find ./ -type f -exec grep -H 'oscar.apps.orderoscar' {} ;

It outputs the following occurences:

1. ./shop/shop/**pycache**/settings.cpython-310.pyc: binary file matches

The .pyc files seem to be immutable from a security perspective as far as i could tell

I've attempted to set a breakpoint in the '/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py'

```py
    def import_module(name, package=None):
        if name == 'oscar.apps.orderoscar':
            name = 'oscar.apps.order'
            set_trace()
```

This breakpoint is never reached.

Any help or tips in the right direction is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In my INSTALLED_APPS, I forgot to separate the oscar entries with comma's